# H1-B LCA "Main worksite" vs "Additional worksite"

Tags: h1-visa

My company amended my H1-B LCA and has added a new worksite as "Additional Worksite". My current location is kept as "Main Worksite". Are there any differences between the Additional or Main worksite? In terms of deciding my base pay or anything?

Comment: I don't think there is any such provision for having a "Main" and an "Additional" worksite by USCIS. Probably your company/attorneys are just using it to track internal records. Did you find this terminology on your LCA or some company/lawyer letter/portal?

Comment: AFAIK the LCA is aimed at U.S. worker protection, so that hiring of a foreign worker will not adversely affect the wages and working conditions of U.S. workers comparably employed. The employer is required to pay the prevailing wage or the actual wage paid by the employer to workers with similar skills and qualifications, whichever is higher. https://www.myvisajobs.com/Wage/Prevailing-Wage-Determination.aspx